# Number of sequences of heads and tails of length $k$ such that the number of heads is never more than $m$ less than the number of tails?

Tags: combinatorics

If I flip a coin $k$ times and write down the sequence of heads and tails. If it any point during flipping I flip $m$ more tails than heads, then I stop.

How many valid sequences of heads/tails can I get from this process (valid sequences being those where I do not stop)

Formulated differently, I start at the origin on the number line and can walk up 1 or down 1. I take $k$ steps, how many walks are there where I never cross the point $k$?

Comment: I suppose this is a generalization of [Dyck words and the Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Applications_in_combinatorics).

Comment: Just to clarify, in your reformulation, you want to never cross the point $m$, not $k$, correct?

Comment: @Tad Er yea k steps never cross the point m of course

Comment: This process can be seen as a 1D random walk, which does not across the point m.